# Stopping jQuery to repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, load, loading

I have an issue. I have a script, that first checks if the content of an iframe is loaded.

1. When the content is loaded, a countdown timer will appear.
2. Once the timer hits 0, a form will run.

My issue is that when the iframe is loaded, and when the countdown begins, I can click on another link in the iframe, and it will start the timer once again.

My script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Loading bar style
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });
});
// on document load:
$(function() {
   // set "waiting" message:
   $("#loadingStatus").html("Waiting for your advertisements to load...");

   // on iframe load:

   $('#iFrame').load(function() {

       $("#loadingStatus").html($("#isDone").html());



   });
});

$(function count() {
   var seconds = <?php echo $exposure[$r['exposure']]; ?>;
   setTimeout(updateCountdown, 1000);

   function updateCountdown() {
      seconds--;

      if (seconds > 0) {
         $("#countdown").text("You must view this advertisement for " + seconds + " seconds.");
         //$('#progressbar').progressbar({ value: Math.round((seconds/10)*100) });
         setTimeout(updateCountdown, 1000);
      } else {
         submitForm();
      }
   }
});                                                                             


function submitForm() {
                $("#countdown").empty().html('<img src="..ify/dream/images/loading.gif" />');
                $.post(
                    'index.php?i=v&p=k&key=DSF79SADFHSA7D9FGSAD097FSAD7F9779ASDFGS9', 
                    $('form').serialize(),
                    function (data) {
                        proccessData(data);
                    }
                ); 

}  

function proccessData (data) {
            $('#statusF').hide().html('');

            if(data=='success'){
                $('form').fadeOut();
                $('#countdown').addClass('noti-success').html('Advertisement validated!').slideDown();
                redirect("?i=l");  
            }
            else {
                $('#countdown').addClass('noti-error').html(data).fadeIn();
            }
        }

  </script>
```

Comment: please make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) of your code

Comment: look up
    '.stop(true)' and 'queue:' property

Comment: But where to add this stop command?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `clearTimeout` method to stop a timeout that is no longer wanted.

Declare a variable to hold the handle to the timer, and assign the result of `setTimeout` to it. Clear the timer if the function is called again and the handle is set:

```
var timer = null;

function count() {
   var seconds = <?php echo $exposure[$r['exposure']]; ?>;
   if (timer != null) window.clearTimeout(timer);
   timer = setTimeout(updateCountdown, 1000);

   function updateCountdown() {
      timer = null;
      seconds--;

      if (seconds > 0) {
         $("#countdown").text("You must view this advertisement for " + seconds + " seconds.");
         //$('#progressbar').progressbar({ value: Math.round((seconds/10)*100) });
         timer = setTimeout(updateCountdown, 1000);
      } else {
         submitForm();
      }
   }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/deeWy/1/

Comment: I tried this, but with no luck. :( 

It shows example "You must view this advertisement for 7 seconds". Then I click a link in the iFrame, and it jumps back to you must view this advertisement for 13 seconds, and then jumps back to 7 seconds again.

Comment: @Oliver 'Oli' Jensen: I'm not sure what's happening in your code... The function only runs once when the page loads, so is that code in the iframe? Which code is in the page and which code is in the iframe?

Comment: @Oliver 'Oli' Jensen: I removed the `ready` event on the function in the code above, and added jsfiddle demo.

Answer (score 1):

this is most case the jquery ajax.

but you can solve it by set up the ajax async by defaut to false.

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

and put it under document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
      // another code here...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var countDownTimer = null;
    var seconds = <?php echo $exposure[$r['exposure']]; ?>;

    function setCountDownTimer(){
      if(countDownTimer)
        clearTimeout(countDownTimer);

      countDownTimer = setTimeout(updateCountdown, 1000);
    };

    function updateCountdown() {
          countDownTimer = null;
          seconds--;

          if (seconds > 0) {
             $("#countdown").text("You must view this advertisement for " + seconds + " seconds.");
             //$('#progressbar').progressbar({ value: Math.round((seconds/10)*100) });
             setCountDownTimer();
          } else {
             submitForm();
          }
     }

// on document load:
$(function() {

   $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });

   // set "waiting" message:
   $("#loadingStatus").html("Waiting for your advertisements to load...");

   // on iframe load:

   $('#iFrame').load(function() {

       $("#loadingStatus").html($("#isDone").html());

       //Attached click event to the link inside iframe to restart the timer
       var iframe = $('#iFrame');
       iframe.contents().find("linkSelector").click(function(){
         window.top.setCountDownTimer();
       });

   });

   setCountDownTimer();
});



function submitForm() {
                $("#countdown").empty().html('<img src="..ify/dream/images/loading.gif" />');
                $.post(
                    'index.php?i=v&p=k&key=DSF79SADFHSA7D9FGSAD097FSAD7F9779ASDFGS9', 
                    $('form').serialize(),
                    function (data) {
                        proccessData(data);
                    }
                ); 

}  

function proccessData (data) {
            $('#statusF').hide().html('');

            if(data=='success'){
                $('form').fadeOut();
                $('#countdown').addClass('noti-success').html('Advertisement validated!').slideDown();
                redirect("?i=l");  
            }
            else {
                $('#countdown').addClass('noti-error').html(data).fadeIn();
            }
        }
```

Comment: If I use this, when the iframe has loaded, nothing more appear. No text, no nothing.

Comment: Yes, you have to execute this once iframe loads

Comment: How will it look then, if I have to input it with the rest of my code? I am not sure where to put the code above.